# Solving $4\sin^4x-4\sin^2x+1=0, x \in [0,2\pi\rangle$.

Tags: trigonometry

I am having problem solving this trig equation. Every time I try to simplify or substitute $\sin x$ with $u$, I get $x=\emptyset$.

How do I go about solving this equation?

$4\sin^4x-4\sin^2x+1=0, x \in [0,2\pi\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side is $(2\sin^2x-1)^2$, so you need to solve $\sin^2x=\frac12$ (i.e. $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x=0$) for $2x\in[0,\,4\pi)$. The solution is therefore $x\in\big\{\frac{\pi}{4},\,\frac{3\pi}{4},\,\frac{5\pi}{4},\,\frac{7\pi}{4}\big\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $$\sin^2(x)=t$$ and solve the quadratic.

Comment: Wow I am overcomplicating things way too much. I think I need a break, my brain is toast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is same like 
$$4t^2 -4t + 1 = 0, \ \text{setting}\ t=\sin^2(x)$$
                $$(2t-1)^2     = 0$$
                 $$t = 1/2.$$